# If $f(x)=3 f(1-x)+1$ for all $x$, the value of $f(2016)$?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> If $$f(x)=3 f(1-x)+1$$
>   for all $x$, what is the value of $f(2016)$?

I am not sure how to do this, because I see two "$f$"s.

All I could try is substituting,

$$f(x)=3(1-2016)+1\\
=-6044$$

Which I am pretty sure wrong.

How do I deal with this question? when there is $f$ around a braket?

Thank you

Comment: If you put for $x\rightarrow 1-x$ what happens?

Comment: f (x)=3f (1-x)+1=3 (3f (1-(1-x))+1)+1=3 (f (x)+1)+1=9f (x)+4 so 8f (x)=-4 and f (x)=-1/2.

Comment: Do you *know* what f around a bracket means?

Comment: It's the value that I substitute for x for a function isn't it? @fleablood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**  $f(2016) = 3f(-2015) + 1$. But $f(-2015)= 3f(2016)+1$. Conclude

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$f(x)=3(3f(1-(1-x))+1)+1$$

$$=9f(x)+4$$

$\implies$

$$f(x)=-\frac12=f(2016)$$

Answer (score 1):

f (2016)= 3f (-2015)+1

f (-2015)=3f (1-(-2015))+1=3f (2016)+1.

So f (2016)=3 (3f (2016)+1)+1=9f (2016)+4

So -8f (2016)=4

So f (2016)=-1/2.

Now the real question, is how to solve for **all** x.

Comment: Any reason for lack of MathJax?

Comment: $f$ is a constant functggh byebye

Comment: Only, that it's a pain on this phone app and this question didn't seem to need it.  Yes, it is a constant function.  I'm hoping the op will be able to convince themselves of that fact.